# Finding the closed-form formula to a recurrence with summation of terms

Tags: combinatorics, summation, recurrence-relations, recursion

I am currently trying to work through this recurrence problem but am having a hard time coming up with the solution:

$g\left(n\right)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}g\left(i\right)g\left(n-i\right)\right)+1$

Where the base $g(0)=0$.
One thing I noticed was that the values involved in the summation are sort of symmetrical, there would be a $g(2)g(3)$ as well as a $g(3)g(2)$ and this duplicate value would exist for each value of i except for when $i=n-i$, which I wanted to take advantage of. I typically approach closed-form recurrences by creating a polynomial in which I would take a guess for a function and solve for its constants but Im not sure how to extend this idea to something like this.

Comment: What is upper limit in your summation?and what is value of $g(0)$?

Comment: The upper limit is $n$, from $g(n)$ and $g(0)=0$, sorry about that

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: If $g(0)=0$ then upper limit acn be taken as $n-1$.

Comment: @PratikJadhav could you elaborate on that? I see the equivalence but I don't know what sort of approach this opens up.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Edited

Comment: $g(1)=g(1)g(0)+1$. Is an implicit relation intended ?

Comment: I suppose that just zeros out, I'll make the change. Thanks

Comment: @AlexisC.: it does because $g(0)=0$, but it would not otherwise.

Comment: It's https://oeis.org/A007317 if the upper limit is indeed $n-1$, so it has g.f. $3/2-(1/2)\sqrt{(1-5x)/(1-x)}$ and one of the formulas is $g(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k3^{n-k-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{k}{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}$.

Comment: Sorry, what does g.f. stand for? @Sil

Comment: @Sil how did you find that generating function?

Comment: [Generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function), so if you do series expansion of that function, its coefficients are terms of the sequence. In this case $3/2-(1/2)\sqrt{(1-5x)/(1-x)}=x+2x^2+5x^3+15x^4+\dots$. @PratikJadhav It's in the oeis record I've referred.

Comment: @Sil , I tried but I got  f(x)(1-f(x))=1/(1-x)

Comment: @PratikJadhav I got that too at first. The mistake is that the recurrence relation does not (and cannot) hold for $n=0$, that would give $g(0)=1$. So the g.f satisfies $f(x) = f(x)^2 + \frac{z}{1-z}$ and not $f(x) = f(x)^2 + \frac{1}{1-z}$. This gives the above function as one of the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More general approach is to use [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function). In this case, this means finding $$f(x)=g(0)+g(1)x+g(2)x^2+\dots.$$ Then perhaps from the form of $f(x)$ we could extract the coefficients in some way. To find the $f(x)$, first notice that your recurrence definition looks very similar to convolution of two series, i.e. if you multiply $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_nx^n \cdot \sum_{n \geq 0} b_nx^n=\sum_{n \geq 0} c_nx^n$, then 
$$c_n=a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+\dots+a_nb_0=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ib_{n-i},$$ 
which suggests we should take something like $f(x)f(x)$ to get $f(x)$. To see it, notice that since $g(0)=0$, we can write the recurrence as $g(n)-1=\sum_{i=0}^{n}g\left(i\right)g\left(n-i\right)$ for $n\geq 1$. Also notice for $n=0$ the equality does not hold (left side is $-1$, right side $0$), we can correct for this by adding $1$. This means that 
$$
1+(g(0)-1)+(g(1)-1)x+(g(2)-1)x^2+\dots=f(x)f(x)=f(x)^2.
$$
Left side is now equal to $1+f(x)-(1+x+x^2+\dots)=1+f(x)-\frac{1}{1-x}=f(x)-\frac{x}{1-x}$, and so we have found out
$$
f(x)-\frac{x}{1-x}=f(x)^2.
$$
By solving this as a quadratic equation in $f$, we have
$$
f(x)=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-4\frac{x}{1-x}}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{1-5x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}.
$$
Now we expect $f(0)=g(0)=0$, so from this we see 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{1-5x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}.$$

Having a generating function, we can try and deduce the coefficients in a non-recursive way. To do this, we will use series expansions that we already know, in this case [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) is very useful since we can write $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}(1-5x)^{1/2}(1-x)^{-1/2}$. So by the binomial series we get

$$
(1-5x)^{1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{k}(-1)^k5^kx^k=1-\frac{1}{2}5x+\frac{1/2\cdot -1/2}{2}5^2x^2+\dots\\
(1-x)^{-1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-1/2}{k}(-1)^kx^k=1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{-1/2\cdot -3/2}{2}x^2+\dots\\
$$ 
and so 
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{1/2}{i}(-1)^i5^i\cdot \binom{-1/2}{n-i}(-1)^{n-i} x^n\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}5^i\binom{1/2}{i}(-1)^i\cdot \binom{-1/2}{n-i}(-1)^{n-i} x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n}5^i\binom{1/2}{i}\binom{-1/2}{n-i}x^n.\\
\end{align}
Now we can read off the coefficient at $x^n$ to get $g(n)$, so 
$$
\bbox[#ffd,10px]{g(n)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n}5^i\binom{1/2}{i}\binom{-1/2}{n-i}.}
$$
You can possibly further simplify this writting out the generalized binomial coefficients inside the sum, but I wouldn't expect a closed form without the sum involved. For example, you should be able to arrive at 
$$
g(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k3^{n-k-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{k}{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}
$$
as mentioned in https://oeis.org/A007317, which has the additional benefit that all its terms are integers (and so might be for example more suitable for investigating divisibility properties of the sequence).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding it right, wouldn't $g(5)$ represent the fifth term in the sequence? How come its giving $g(5)=0$?

Comment: @AlexisC. $g(5)$ according to highlighted formula gives $-\frac{63}{512}+\frac{175}{512}+\frac{125}{256}+\frac{375}{256}+\frac{3125}{512}+\frac{21875}{512}=51$. According to the last one, it gives $81-108+108-36+6=51$.

Comment: My mistake, I inputted the values incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

We can obtain a generating function for your sequence. First we modify the recurrence relation to state $$g(n) = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^ng(i)g(n-i).$$ Note that this gives the same relation because $g(0)=0$. Also note that this equality does not hold for $n=0$ (that gives $g(0) = g(0)^2 + 1$). Now we define the generating function.

Let
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n) \cdot x^n.$$
Then, by taking the Cauchy product of $f$ with itself we see:
\begin{align*}
f(x)^2 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{i=0}^n g(n-i)g(i)\right)x^n\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{i=0}^n g(n-i)g(i)\right)x^n\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(g(n) - 1\right)x^n\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n)x^n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\\
&= f(x) - \frac{x}{1-x}.
\end{align*}
We obtain that the generating function satisfies the relation 
$$f(x)^2 = f(x) - \frac{x}{1-x}.$$ There are two functions satisfying this relation. Namely:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{1-5 x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\right) \quad\text{ or }\quad f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-5 x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}+1\right).$$ 
Only the first choice has its zeroth term equal to zero and thus we conclude that our generating function is $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{1-5 x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\right) = x + 2x^2 + 5x^3 + 15x^4 + \cdots.$$ As to a closed form of your sequence. We have now shown that your sequence (up to a different zeroth term because they record the coefficients of $f(x)+1$) is sequence [A181768](https://oeis.org/A181768) in the OEIS. You can proceed your research there. The site gives several other ways to calculate the terms of the sequence (see also [A007317](https://oeis.org/A007317)). A *simple* formula might be a bit much to ask.